# Would it be colluding if banks collectively decided not to increase deposit costs?

Tags: banking

I always thought of collusion as consumer paying companies less money. In this case, it would be companies paying consumer less money.

Comment: The result of the collusion doesn't impact the definition of collusion.

Comment: Your question is... a bit confusing.  Typically, the phrase "deposit **costs**" would mean something like *fees that a bank charges it's customers*, but that doesn't mesh with the rest of what you wrote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance.

Comment: 3 for 5 of my questions voted to close. Welcoming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would be colluding. Most countries have well defined laws to prevent companies including banks from indulging in such activities.

Comment: "well defined", certainly not well enforced.

Comment: I wonder if it's still colluding if nothing was actually discussed between companies.